# Keyerror: Cardinality while running trainer from transformers

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-trainer

I encountered this issue while I was running the model.

> ---
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> [/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in **getattr**(self, item)
> 265         try:
> 266             return self.data[item]
> 267         except KeyError:
>
> KeyError: 'cardinality'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Below is the code:

```
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification

model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "distilbert-base-uncased")

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer)  # No loss argument!

from transformers import TFTrainer, TFTrainingArguments


training_args = TFTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./sentiment_model",
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=32,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=500,  # Adjust as needed
    save_total_limit=2,
)

trainer = TFTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_tokenized,
    eval_dataset=val_tokenized,
)

trainer.train() # <- where the error occured
```

I found this was a bug but should be fixed.

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/9495